# Python lambda as constant functor

Tags: python, lambda

I have code with labdas, I have checked each time the function object is created it is different (not reference to same object),
but it doesn't work as I would expect it. Is there any way how to or I should use a functor to do it even if I have constant data which I insert into lambda`s body?

```
pairs = [('abc', 'xyz'), ('123', '987'), ('abc', '987')]

pairLambs = []

for p in pairs:
    pairLambs.append(lambda: print(p))

pairLambs[0]()
pairLambs[1]()
pairLambs[2]()
```

outputs:

```
('abc', '987')
('abc', '987')
('abc', '987')
```

but I need:

```
('abc', 'xyz')
('123', '987')
('abc', '987')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a well-known gotcha - since you don't bind the current value of `p` when defining the `lambda`, when called it uses the current value of `p`. The solution is to use a named arg with default value to bind the "current" (definition time) value of `p`:

```
pairs = [('abc', 'xyz'), ('123', '987'), ('abc', '987')]

pairLambs = []

for p in pairs:
    pairLambs.append(lambda p=p: print(p))

pairLambs[0]()
pairLambs[1]()
pairLambs[2]()
```

Comment: Instead of saying `This is a well-known gotcha`, I think its better to say, `a lambda is evaluated when called. Since all the lambdas refer to the same identifier `p` which changes during iteration, the last object which it points to is the one gets associated with all the lamba expressions`

Comment: @Abhijit: it's _still_ a gotcha - as in "non obvious and not necessarily intuitive behaviour" - and it's well known.

Comment: thanks, I suspected it is something with the naming, but also I had a hunch it must work somehow. The solution with default argument is just what I need!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to 'specialize' function, you should take a look at `functools`:

```
import functools

pairs = [('abc', 'xyz'), ('123', '987'), ('abc', '987')]
pairLambs = []
for p in pairs:
    pairLambs.append(functools.partial(print, p))
```

This gives result you expect.

Comment: Doesn't work with Python 2.x where `print` is a statement not a function.

Comment: yes, actually i did this in python 2.7, just with `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: thanks, however I need the labdas body to be a little more comlex, I'm actually doing GUI app in Qt (PySide) and I want to handle some callbacks for non-gui objects that affect the gui... this was really just an example of the idea

Comment: I am sure you can do much more with `functools` than with lambdas - which are not intended to do complicated things, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is how closures in python work. To achive what you want you can do this:

```
 for p in pairs:
     def closure(_p):
         return lambda: print(_p)
     pairLambs.append(closure(p))
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid defining something new (function, class).
Othewise I would prefer a functor:

`class PairFunctor:
   def __init__(self, pair):
     self.pair = pair
   def __call__(self):
     print(self.pair)
  for p in pairs:
    pairLambs.append(PairFunctor(p))`